# why is my texture displaying so strangely with slick util?

Tags: java, render, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm trying to use slick util to display a logo in the centre of the screen.

```
texture.bind();
glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(x, y);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(x + texture.getTextureWidth(), y);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(x + texture.getTextureWidth(), y + texture.getTextureHeight());
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(x, y + texture.getTextureHeight());
glEnd();
```

But when it renders the texture isn't centred, and a random line is drawn on the right. I have no idea why. Thanks.

Comment: Which corner is it rendered on? Can you post a screenshot showing the "random line"?

Answer (score 1):

FIXED: Make your image a power of 2. I did this, and it now works :D

I can vouch for this. I use LWJGL to render everything in my game I am making, and I use it do render backgrounds, which is okay, but when I render things less than the full size of the display, it shows random lines and the image is slanted. Here is a screenshot picture; http://imageshack.us/f/39/problema.png/     <<<<--- See the split line about a third of the way across, and the line on the left hand side.

And here is my code;

```
        ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.bind();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); //TOP LEFT
        GL11.glVertex2f(0,0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); //TOP RIGHT
        GL11.glVertex2f(ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.getTextureWidth(),0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); //BOTTOM RIGHT
        GL11.glVertex2f(ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.getTextureWidth(), ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); //BOTTOM LEFT
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.getTextureHeight());
    GL11.glEnd();
```